# How to make a content in the grid to spot a space around the cell by half-a-gap?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I need to make this:
[image]

You can see that the button takes 100% width of the grid column and moreover takes half of the column gap space around. I don't know how to achieve it.

Grid container:

```
#header.about-page-header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    grid-row-gap: 45px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "title    title    title    ."
        "subtitle subtitle subtitle ."
        ".        .        .        ."
        "contacts contacts .        btn";
    align-content: end;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The button:

```
a.about-page-header__btn {
    grid-area: btn;
    width: auto;
    justify-self: stretch;
}
```

Currently, my button takes just 100% width of the column. But how to make it to place half of a gap around?

Comment: negative margin ? -30px on each side

Comment: @TemaniAfif negative margin here is like a transform translate, it doesn't increase width of the button.

Comment: @AlexanderShpindler Actually, yes it does - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KGKBwj

Comment: are you sure ? https://jsfiddle.net/ozgd43a6/

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh, thanks, I had max-width: 100% in the button's css.